# Bazel: Mixing a Linux remote execution platform with a Mac OS local platform

Tags: bazel

## Goal

I am using Bazel to build a multiplatform C++ client (iOS, OSX, Android, Windows).

iOS and OSX are built locally on my Mac (out of necessity). Android and Windows are built inside a Docker container.

At the end of the build I have a Bazel rule that takes each `cc_binary` rule for each platform and puts them in a `.zip`.

I'd like to utilize Bazel's remote execution API to build some of my binaries in the container and others locally and then reference a shared cache to collate them together -- all with one `bazel build` command.

## Bazel support

Bazel claims that these types of `multiplatform` builds -- where the `host` (OSX x64), `execution` (Linux x64), and `target` platforms (many) are all different -- are possible.

See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/platforms.html

## My experience

However, I hit this exact issue: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5397 (where `docker-sandbox` is a correct proxy for `remote` builds.)

This, alongside the below Github issue, makes me question Bazel's claim about `multiplatform` builds.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5309

Fundamentally, these issues seem to say that local targets for one platform (e.g., OSX) cannot be built alongside remote targets on another platform (e.g. Linux).

## Question

I was wondering:

(1) Is what I am trying to do fundamentally at odds with Bazel's design? If so, what is meant by Bazel being `multiplatform`?

(2) Is there a workaround I can employ that maintains hermiticity and stays within the Bazel build system? It could be possible to mount a Docker volume and then write a script that combines the Docker cache with my local cache, but it seems like Bazel was built to handle my use case. Am I missing something here?

Related questions: [Does bazel support remote execution on different platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487061/does-bazel-support-remote-execution-on-different-platforms) (Doesn't have a satisfactory answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (1) Is what I am trying to do fundamentally at odds with Bazel's design?

In theory no, in practice yes. Bazel provides functionality which allows users to support your use-case, but it is not implemented by default.

Specifically, as described in the linked Bazel issues: Bazel *rules* currently make assumptions about the relationship between the host and target platforms which don't hold in your case, e.g. it will auto-detect the JDK files on your host (macOS) and then default to using these JDK files across all Java actions - regardless of target platform.

> If so, what is meant by Bazel being multiplatform?

In practice, it means that you can run `bazel build ...` on multiple platforms and expect that Bazel will transform your inputs into outputs compatible for the current platform.

> (2) Is there a workaround I can employ that maintains hermiticity and stays within the Bazel build system?

Yes, you can run `bazel build ...` from within a Windows VM or Docker container. This was the workaround that the Bazel team recommended when I asked this question.

Relevant advanced Bazel features:

- If you want to build for multiple target platforms with one Bazel invocation, have a look at [Bazel user-defined transitions](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/config.html#user-defined-transitions) (this would allow you to build the same rule for multiple platforms, e.g. iOS and macOS at once, but require you to write your own rules).
- If you don't want to run `bazel build` from within containers/VMs, you can write your [own C++ toolchain](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html). At its core, Bazel gives each action a sandbox with all dependent files and guarantees that it will execute a specific command. In a custom C++ toolchain, you could tell Bazel to call a script instead of clang, which takes the command + the files and executes them from within a VM or container. This is likely a *lot* of work, but is definitely possible.

Comment: `Yes, you can run bazel build ... from within a Windows VM or Docker container.` This wouldn't support my requirement for building iOS and OSX artifacts. AFAIK compiling for OSX and iOS is not possible inside a Docker container for both technical and legal reasons.

Comment: Correct! The suggestion is to break your build command into 3 parts: one for your macOS/iOS artefacts, another for Linux (run from within the container), and one for the Windows ones (run from the Windows VM). This is not great UX but will likely work out of the box (especially if you're building cc_library/cc_binary targets).

Comment: Okay - yes my question was essentially, do I have to fallback to the approach you just described or is it possible to do it all in a single `bazel build ...` so that my `zip` rule (which already implements user-defined transitions to account for the platform differences) can simply depend each platform's `cc_binary` rule using `deps`. Sounds like the answer for now is to take the slight UX hit.

Comment: Update: It appears I was able to resolve my problem by adding `build:remote --incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution`. The mingw-w64 compiler is now correctly getting chosen instead of wrapped-clang. It isn't 100% clear to me why the usage of the new platforms API causes bazel to use the containerized compiler rather than clang, but hey it's progress.